# "Undefined reference" error in communication between Arduino and contributed IMU library

Tags: c++, arduino, accelerometer

I'm attempting to use the FreeIMU library to send gravity compensated acceleration data from an accelerometer Arduino board to my computer. Here is the portion of the .pde file that is raising an error:

```
float q[4];
int raw_values[9];
float ypr[3]; // yaw pitch roll
char str[256];
float values[9];


// Set the FreeIMU object
FreeIMU my3IMU = FreeIMU();
//The command from the PC
char cmd;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  my3IMU.init(true);

  // LED
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()) {
    cmd = Serial.read();
    if(cmd=='v') {
      sprintf(str, "FreeIMU library by %s, FREQ:%s, LIB_VERSION: %s, IMU: %s", FREEIMU_DEVELOPER, FREEIMU_FREQ, FREEIMU_LIB_VERSION, FREEIMU_ID);
      Serial.print(str);
      Serial.print('\n');
    }
    else if(cmd=='r') {
      uint8_t count = serial_busy_wait();
      for(uint8_t i=0; i<count; i++) {
        my3IMU.getRawValues(raw_values);
        sprintf(str, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,", raw_values[0], raw_values[1], raw_values[2], raw_values[3], raw_values[4], raw_values[5], raw_values[6], raw_values[7], raw_values[8], raw_values[9], raw_values[10]);
        Serial.print(str);
        Serial.print('\n');
      }
    }
    else if(cmd=='g') {
      uint8_t count = serial_busy_wait();
      for(uint8_t i=0; i<count; i++) {
        my3IMU.getQ(q);
        my3IMU.getValues(values);
        float acc[3];
        acc[0] = values[0];
        acc[1] = values[1];
        acc[2] = values[2];
        my3IMU.gravityCompensateAcc(acc, q);
        sprintf(str, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,", &acc[0], &acc[1], &acc[2], &values[3], &values[4], &values[5], &values[6], &values[7], &values[8], &values[9], &values[10]);
        Serial.print(str);
        Serial.print('\n');
      }
    }
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
FreeIMU_serial_edit1.cpp.o: In function `loop':
/Applications/FreeIMU_serial_edit1.ino:70: undefined reference to `FreeIMU::gravityCompensateAcc(float*, float*)'
```

The function in question is defined in FreeIMU.cpp:

```
    /**
 * Compensates the accelerometer readings in the 3D vector acc expressed in the sensor frame for gravity
 * @param acc the accelerometer readings to compensate for gravity
 * @param q the quaternion orientation of the sensor board with respect to the world
*/
void FreeIMU::gravityCompensateAcc(float * acc, float * q) {
  float g[3];

  // get expected direction of gravity in the sensor frame
  g[0] = 2 * (q[1] * q[3] - q[0] * q[2]);
  g[1] = 2 * (q[0] * q[1] + q[2] * q[3]);
  g[2] = q[0] * q[0] - q[1] * q[1] - q[2] * q[2] + q[3] * q[3];

  // compensate accelerometer readings with the expected direction of gravity
  acc[0] = acc[0] - g[0];
  acc[1] = acc[1] - g[1];
  acc[2] = acc[2] - g[2];
}
```

The other functions from the C++ object my3IMU, such as my3IMU.getQ, work fine; I don't understand why the compiler reports that gravityCompensateAcc is undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered your same problem.
The answer is pretty simple, the function definition is inside an #if statement, more precisely `#if HAS_MS5611()` around line 519.
Move it outside the `#if...#endif` statement and it will work.